# Euler's programming function : differential equation as a parameter

Tags: linear-programming, approximation, calculus

I have a programming function written for Eurler's approximations. Currently the function only takes 3 parameters.

1. step size
2. starting f(x)
3. endting f(x) which is what we are approximating

Each time I have to use Euler, I have to keep on changing my function's differential equation.

E.g. 
euqation 1

```
f'(x) = 3x^{2} - 7
```

equation 2

```
f'(x) = f(x) + 2
```

I want to send **differential equation as a paramter.** How can I do so?

I am using C#, VBA. Don't have Matlab installed at the moment. But I am willing to try out in Python although I am new to it.

ps: I [checked on this question. Quite hard to understand the case there...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39313/setting-up-and-solving-differential-equation-with-the-euler-method)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this can help :

I use C# as an example

```
public static double equation(double x, Func<double, double> f)
{
    return f(x);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //f'(x) = 3x^{2} - 7
    double result1 = equation(5, x => Math.Pow(3 * x, 1 / 2) - 7);

    //f'(x) = f(x) + 2
    double result2 = equation(5, x => x + 2); 

    Console.WriteLine(result1);
    Console.WriteLine(result2);
}
```

Comment: Let me give it a try. Will take sometime to get back. Hope you don't mind :)